# Will there be token burn at any point in time in future?

Tags: token

Will there be token burn at any point in time in future ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ways to burn tokens?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/330/ways-to-burn-tokens)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questions about the future of Cardano can't be effectively addressed on this site and would be better addressed directly to the Cardano Team on their [forum](https://forum.cardano.org/). This site is not operated by the Cardano organization. This site is a place to ask questions about how Cardano works and to ask for help using it.

Answer (score 3):

Decreasing the supply of ADA by burning tokens is a method to artificially raise the value of the remaining supply. It has been repeatedly stated that all ADA has an owner/purpose and *supply will not be reduced by burning ADA.*

**ADA relies on use and utility to increase its value.**

Answer (score 1):

You can burn your ADA by making an address with no valid private/public keys if you want to, and send coins to it.

There appears to be no rational reason to do such things though, what motivation is there to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to native tokens, that all depends on the minting policy. If you are referring to ADA, then no. Charles has answered this question many times in AMAs.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Token burning is funny and Stupid. Think about it. You bought it and you want to artificially pump your bags by burning the supply. If you really believe ADA is a SOV and real money why would we want to burn it? Any serious coin should not do a coin burn. ADA will never ever do a burn or reduce the supply! Our max supply is 45 billion and that will remain. Nothing more, nothing less